# Define variable type

Tags: c++, printing, types, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to convert a working define which prints the argument into a proper function, but I'm unsure of the variable type.

The working method I have is:

```
#define WARN(x)     std::cout << "WARNING! " << x << "!" << std::endl;
```

Which I can then pass a sentence similar to using std::cout

```
WARN("This is a test warning." << " And this is some more stuff...");
```

However, I feel this should be more neatly wrapped into a function rather than using a define.

Please could you help me understand how the preprocessor is interpreting the variable x, and how I can translate the define into a function.

P.S. I am aware that I could use a variadic function, but I'd rather not have to pass the number of arguments and would rather avoid variadic altogether anyway.

Comment: Don't mistake a variadic function for a variadic template, which knows how many arguments are passed and their types.

Comment: I did not realise they were two separate things. I'll look into the template, thanks!

Comment: If it's only a single argument, that variadic part becomes redundant, too. A regular template suffices.

Answer (score 0):

> but I'm unsure of the variable type.

That's where use of function templates can provide a clean solution.

```
template <typename T>
void WARN(T const& x)
{
  std::cout << "WARNING! " << x << "!" << std::endl;
}
```

is a good replacement for

```
#define WARN(x)     std::cout << "WARNING! " << x << "!" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but will this work for multiple variables? For example, can I pass:

"This is one string" << " and this is another."

As the arguments as I could for the define version? As the function appears to only accept a single argument.

Comment: @user7119460, yes, you can have function templates with more than one argument.